# Making all the UI form as Readonly/Disable?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

We have a requirement  where we need to make all the form input elements as `readonly` when user access is set as **"READ ONLY"**.

We are using a widget based template approach in our coding, where the widgets are specified in the template HTML and that are used in the corresponding JS file.

I have tried with the following code in my JS `postcreate` method :

```
var item=dojo.query("#showtech_log_title_pane"); // id of the content pane

for (var i=0;i{
   dijit.byId(item[i]).set('readOnly',true);
}
```

> Error : dijit by id-> undefined or null

also,

```
var container = dojo.query("#showtech_log_title_pane");

dojo.query('input', container).forEach(
  function(inputElem){
    inputElem.disabled = 'disabled';
  }
)
```

> Error: Create Element not a method

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Fixing those would be a good start. ;-) The *disabled* attribute is boolean, so `inputElem.disabled = true`, but a string works as well since it evaluates to true (but not when setting to 'false', you need `false`).

Comment: There's an error in the first line of the second code block, you're using two single quotes and ending it with a double quote. And the for loop in the first block.

Comment: @RobG by doing that i am getting the following error:
There was an error while parsing and rendering the content. (Unable to resolve constructor for: 'xwt.widget.LicenseInfoDialogue').

I put the code in postCreate and addonLoad function

Answer (score 2):

To disable a widget you have to get a reference to it , and set its disabled attribute to true.

In your case, you have to iterate through all inputs that have ids ( to be sure that's a created widget ) then get enclosing widget of input and set it to disabled

Below a working example :

```js
require([ "dojo/ready", 
    "dojo/query",
          "dijit/registry",
          "dojo/_base/array",
    "dijit/TitlePane", 
    "dojo/domReady!"],
function (ready, query, registry, array, TitlePane) {
 ready(function(){
      //get all 
      var inputs = dojo.query('input', "enclosing_input_div");
      array.forEach(inputs,function(input){
        //check if a it's a created widget input (all widgets have theire own id )
       if(input.id)
          if(registry.byId(input.id)) // recheck if it it has enclosing widget
            registry.byId(input.id).set("disabled",true)
      })
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
    dojoConfig= {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
    };
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="enclosing_input_div">
    <div id="tp1" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'tp1'">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>TextField :</td>
          <td><input  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>NumberTextBox :</td>
          <td><input id="numberTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberTextBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Checkbox :</td>
          <td><input id="checkBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>RadioButton :</td>
          <td><input id="radioButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here is also a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/xowt72zb/3/)

Comment: By doing that i am getting the following error: There was an error while parsing and rendering the content. (Unable to resolve constructor for: 'xwt.widget.LicenseInfoDialogue'). I put the code in postCreate function and even outside postcreate function

Comment: So , please post the whole organized code , so that we can see where you'll make changes

Comment: Below is the some part of my program. Can you please check and let me know where to add your functionality.